# Y position off on iPhone x

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I'm trying to draw a a line at the top of a table view as follows:

```
func addTopLineToTableView() {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1.0)
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

This works perfectly on every device except an iPhone X.

I've tried getting the `safeAreaInsets` and the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

[image: Table border working]

Above is what the end result should look like. Here the table view has a red background and my green CALayer is right at the top as expected. It has been placed there using the function above. This is the way it looks on every device except the iPhone X.

[image: Table border not working]

Here is what happens when the same code is run on an iPhone X.

Comment: Your should be more specific about what “it doesn’t work” means. What are you expecting? What do you get? Screenshots would be useful.

Comment: You haven't told us what you expect your code to do, and you haven't told us how the code fails to meet your expectations. You haven't told us what you tried to do with the safe area inset.

Comment: Just curious, are you married to `CALayer`? You're ostensibly just drawing a 1pt-divider line so why not just use a `UIView` with constraints?

Comment: @iabuseservers I've tried with both, and they both work, it's the positioning that's the problem

Comment: If `tableView` is properly positioned using constraints and the divider is anchored to `tableView` then there is no reason why it shouldn't work. Post your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Like friends said before, the line can be set to the parts, you can extend the view

```
extension UIView {
@IBInspectable var topBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return 0.0   // Just to satisfy property
    }
    set {
        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: bounds.width, height: newValue))
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.addSubview(line)
        let views = ["line": line]
        let metrics = ["lineWidth": newValue]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[line]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[line(==lineWidth)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }
}
}
```

Such use

```
testView.topBorderWidth = 1
```